# Toggle same table-row with 2 different toggle functions

Tags: jquery, html, toggle, tablerow

I am attempting to toggle a details row via two different sources.

1. If the user clicks on either the Name or the AddressAlert, then that specific detail row gets shown or hidden
2. If the user clicks on "toggle all" then ALL the details rows get shown or hidden.

The issue is that the two separate toggle functions don't know what the other one is up to. So, for example, if the "toggle  all" was just clicked, and now all the details rows are shown, clicking on an individual Name should hide that details row. However, since the individual toggle function is up to "show", it takes 2 clicks to hide the details for that row.

the HTML:

```
<div id="toggleAll"></div>
<table>
    <tr class="infoRow"><td class="addressAlert"></td><td class="name"></td></tr>
    <tr class="details"></tr>
    <tr class="infoRow"><td class="addressAlert"></td><td class="name"></td></tr>
    <tr class="details"></tr>
    <tr class="infoRow"><td class="addressAlert"></td><td class="name"></td></tr>
    <tr class="details"></tr>
</table>
```

The javascript:

```
//toggles beween showing and hiding the details for specific row
$(
    function(){
        //if click on carrier name or address alert symbol
        $('.name, .addressAlert').toggle(
            function() {
            //gets the row clicked on, and finds the next row (the details row)
            detailsTds = $(this).parents("tr.infoRow").next();
            //adds the "shown" class, which sets the display to table-row
            detailsTds.addClass("shown");
            },
            function(){
            //gets the row clicked on, and finds the next row (the details row)
            detailsTds = $(this).parents("tr.infoRow").next();
            //removes the "shown" class, thereby setting the display to none
            detailsTds.removeClass("shown");
            }
        );  
    }
);

//toggle ALL details 
$(
    function(){
        //if click on carrier name or address alert symbol
        $('#toggleAll').toggle(
            function() {
            $('.details').addClass("shown");
            $('#toggleAll').text('[-] Hide all addresses');
            },
            function(){
            $('.details').removeClass("shown");
            $('#toggleAll').text('[+] Show all addresses');
            }
        );  
    }
);
```

Comment: For what its worth the toggleClass function on jquery might also be worth familiarising yourself with. It doesn't help directly with the two things toggling the same thing but would allow you to write cleaner code without the two near identical functions (since they just differ by the add/remove class call generally).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use click() instead of toggle(), then show or hide based on the class that is currently applied to the row.

Answer (score 0):

Could you reference directly to the class?

Comment: that you can access the DOM of the row directly from the CLASS for example $(".infoRow") and the modifyit as you intend... I think it could be the solution

Answer (score 0):

why don't you replace the functions in the first toggle:
"$('.name, .addressAlert').toggle"

and then initialize all the infoRows with shown class-
so the first time it will be pressed it will be shown, even if the user pressed the "toggle ALL"